# WHY cannot I use my own UIColor to change the UITabBarIte's title color?

Tags: objective-c, uicolor

I try to set the UITabBarItem's title's color use method as below:

```
UIColor *sColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1/255.0 green:161/255.0 blue:171/255.0];
UITabBarItem *b_item = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"test" image:normal_image selectedImage:selected_image];
[b_item setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:sColor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName, [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13], NSFontAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

but those code just doesn't make any sense,once i change the code:

```
UIColor *sColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1/255.0 green:161/255.0 blue:171/255.0];
```

into those code:

```
UIColor *sColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

and this code works.
I have no idea why i couldn't use my own defined color value.Please give me some help!

Comment: ***UIColor without alpha...*** **How can you run this code??**

Comment: [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0/255.0 green:161.0/255.0 blue:171.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding alpha to the method like so:

```
UIColor *sColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1/255.0 green:161/255.0 blue:171/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

**REVISED ANSWER BASED ON USERS COMMENT**

If it's not the alpha then maybe it's the way you are setting the colour to the barbuttonitem?

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
    NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:13.0f],                                                         
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:1/255.0 green:161/255.0 blue:171/255.0 alpha:1]
    } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Note that I have set the forState to UIControlStateNormal. In your question it is UIControlStateSelected which only works if the user selects the button.

Comment: I'm sorry,i laid the alpha value off in my question,in fact i did set the alpha value,but it just didn't work.

Comment: I have revised my answer. I hope it helps

Comment: What i want to do is to change the color of the UITabBarItem's title into a different one once it was selected by the user,so I set the UIControlStateSelected.......Anyway,thank you for you answer.

Comment: I guess there must be something other that i need to change,i'll try to find some other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Add alpha:1.0 at end,

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:1/255.0 green:161/255.0 blue:171/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: Thank you very much,i laid the alpha value off in my question,in fact i did set the alpha value,but it just didn't work.